# jquery get not activating view function

Tags: python, jquery, django

I have this jquery funtcion in my django project that returns pk values to my view function in order to print a pdf with the database values. However, it seems that the view funtction is not saving my pdf when using the get function in jquery. why?

my template:

```
<script>

  let getValues2 = () => $("input[name='checkb']:checked").map((i,el) => el.id.trim()).get();

  console.log('getValues2 ',getValues2())

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.print').on('click', () => {
      $.get('eprint/ticked/', {
    marked: getValues2()
      });
      console.log('print: ',getValues2())
    });
    $('.delete').on('click', () => {
      $.get('edelete/ticked/', {
    marked: getValues2()
      });
      console.log('delete: ',getValues2())
    });
  });


</script>


<td id='row1'><button class='print'><i class="bi bi-sim"></i></button>

  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id={{l.pk}} name="checkb"></label>
  <form>
```

urls.py:

```
path('eprint/ticked/',views.eprint,name='eprint'),
```

views.py:

```
def eprint(request):

    print('eprint')
    g=request.GET
    checked=g.getlist('marked[]')
    print(checked)

    res=[Concert.objects.get(pk=l) for l in checked] 

    buffer=io.BytesIO()
    pdf=canvas.Canvas(buffer)
    pdf.setFont("Helvetica",14)
    
    for l in res:
        pdf.drawString(1,100,l.cname)
    
    pdf.drawString(1,100,"test")
    pdf.showPage()
    pdf.save()
    buffer.seek(0)
    
    return FileResponse(buffer,as_attachment=True,filename='test.pdf')
```

Comment: It appears that the PDF library renders the output of the HTML without interpreting or executing the JS. You most likely need another library which does execute JS, if one even exists.

Comment: it executes if I add a href like this: <button class='print'><a href='eprint/ticked'><i class="bi bi-sim"></i></a></button>
but then there are no values, because no script is called. so maybe I need to redirect from the jquery?